# Use variable as part of the column name in WHILE Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to delete multiple columns in a table, how can I use variable as part of the column name in WHILE Loop? Thanks.

```
DECLARE  @colnum INT
Set @colnum = 13
WHILE @colnum <=37
BEGIN

ALTER TABLE PC$
DROP COLUMN F+ @colnum

SET @colnum = @colnum +1
END;
```

Comment: What is `F` in `DROP COLUMN F+ @colnum`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE  @colnum INT
Declare @strsql varchar(max)
Set @colnum = 13
WHILE @colnum <=37
BEGIN

set @strsql ='ALTER TABLE PC$
DROP COLUMN F' + cast(@colnum as varchar(20))

exec(@strsql )

SET @colnum = @colnum +1
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could construct a dynamic sql snippet and execute it:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = N'alter table pc$ drop column f' + cast(@colnum as nvarchar(16))
exec (@sql)
```